# Spring Boot App fails to register RequestContextListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

I'm creating simple REST controllers, for which in my spring boot app I have added the configuration for `RequestContextListener`

```
@Configuration
@WebListener
public class DataApiRequestContextListener extends RequestContextListener {

}
```

In the controller I try ot build location header for successful post request

```
@Async("webExecutor")
@PostMapping("/company")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Object>> save(@RequestBody Company company) {

    Company savedCompany = companyRepository.save(company);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(savedCompany.getId()).toUri();

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Status for POST Request is :: " + response.getStatusCodeValue());
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Data for POST Request is :: " + response.getHeaders().getLocation().toString());
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```

I get the exception

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current ServletRequestAttributes`

when I'm trying to build the location URI using `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` at this line

```
URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(savedCompany.getId()).toUri();
```

Comment: Use saveAndFlush instead of save and check if the exception still coming.

Comment: ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest() seems to be not available when process request @async, moving out async should work or use fromRequestUri  if need aysnc, check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromRequestUri` if using `@async`

```
@Async("webExecutor")
@PostMapping("/company")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Object>> save(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody Company company) {

    Company savedCompany = companyRepository.save(company);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequestUri(request).path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(savedOrganization.getId()).toUri();

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Status for POST Request is :: " + response.getStatusCodeValue());
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Data for POST Request is :: " + response.getHeaders().getLocation().toString());
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```

**OR without `@async` should work and return you location uri.**

```
@PostMapping("/company")
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Object>> save(@RequestBody Company company) {

    Company savedCompany = companyRepository.save(company);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(savedCompany.getId()).toUri();

    ResponseEntity<Object> response = ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Status for POST Request is :: " + response.getStatusCodeValue());
    LOGGER.debug("Reponse Data for POST Request is :: " + response.getHeaders().getLocation().toString());
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
}
```